# Cannot run NPM AUDIT FIX

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, compiler-errors, package.json

We have a problem where we've rebuilt a Windows PC and after cloning the project that we've been working on just fine, it will no build compile.

The project was an Angular 7 build and we have NVM installed and were using V14 just fine before the rebuild.

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
    "build-dev": "ng serve --configuration=local --open",
    "android": "tns run android --bundle",
    "ios": "tns run ios --bundle",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "prodbuild": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compodoc": "npx compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.22",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.11.4",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/youtube-player": "^8.2.3",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^3.1.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "^0.4.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.15.2",
    "@ngx-gallery/core": "^4.0.2-beta.0",
    "@ngx-gallery/lightbox": "^4.0.2-beta.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^10.0.0",
    "@zxing/browser": "0.0.9",
    "@zxing/library": "^0.18.5",
    "@zxing/ngx-scanner": "^1.3.0",
    "amazing-time-picker": "^1.8.0",
    "angular-plotly.js": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-vertical-timeline": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.11.0",
    "blob-polyfill": "^4.0.20190430",
    "canvas-toBlob": "^1.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "dom-to-image-more": "^2.8.0",
    "exif-js": "^2.3.0",
    "export-from-json": "^1.1.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "mat-select-autocomplete": "^1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "~7.0.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.4.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng-pwa-tools": "0.0.15",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-image-compress": "^7.0.7",
    "ng2-org-chart": "^1.1.2",
    "ngx-countdown": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-export-as": "^1.2.5",
    "ngx-gallery": "^5.9.1",
    "ngx-image-compress": "^7.2.4",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.0.1",
    "ngx-mask": "^7.6.5",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.3.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-pica": "^1.1.4",
    "ngx-pipes": "^2.3.10",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.3",
    "ngx-timeline": "^5.0.0",
    "pdfmake": "0.1.36",
    "plotly.js": "^1.54.7",
    "pptxgenjs": "^3.2.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.33.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "~5.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.10",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^0.18.7",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "angular-calendar": "0.26.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "date-fns": "1.30.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.17.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "saturn-datepicker": "7.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.8",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.centralogic.tapinnative",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.1.0"
    }
  },
  "bundledDependencies": [
    "date-fns",
    "angular-calendar",
    "saturn-datepicker"
  ]
}
```

This creates a huge package-lock.json of over 18000 lines.

There were initial issues with gyp and node-sass that we seem to have resolved by installing Python 2.7 etc.

The errors in VS Code terminal now when trying to build:

```
npm ERR! Errors were found in your package-lock.json, run  npm install  to fix them.
npm ERR!     Invalid: lock file's angular-calendar@0.31.0 does not satisfy angular-calendar@0.26.4
npm ERR!     Invalid: lock file's date-fns@2.29.3 does not satisfy date-fns@1.30.1
npm ERR!     Invalid: lock file's saturn-datepicker@8.0.5 does not satisfy saturn-datepicker@7.1.2
```

Really baffled as this is the same package-lock.json and package.json that are in the repos and were fine before.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68515875/how-to-fix-npm-err-errors-were-found-in-your-package-lock-json

Comment: Tried most of these recommendations and still was getting errors. Then after a reboot and -global install of packages... it started working! thanks all for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd delete the `package-lock.json`, then run `npm install --force`.